# Define projection of GeoTIFF in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I want to load a satellite picture into ArcMap. The file has no coordinate system, but the metadata say it is 'WGS 84 / UTM zone 31 N'. However, when I perform 'define projection' the image is located near the equator, whereas it should be located in Northern France. How should I solve this?

[image]

```
entityID = MEN-31-45_UR_2000
lines = 512
samples = 512
FileFormat = GeoTIFF
FileSize = 1213179837
Platform = Landsat
Sensor = ETM
UtmZone = 31
ColorCompositeRGB = 7,4,2
RowStart = 1
ColStart = 1
RowCount = 19635
ColCount = 21516
Projection = UTM
Datum = WGS84
Units = Meters
XStart = 499512.375
YStart = 5543941.125
XIncrement = 14.25
YIncrement = -14.25
ULLat = 50.047762
ULLong = 2.993189
URLat = 49.969161
URLong = 7.269105
LLLat = 47.530835
LLLong = 2.993522
LRLat = 47.458851
LRLong = 7.061480
SCLat = 48.770736
SCLong = 5.079598
ComponentCount = 13
EarliestAcqDate = 19990902
LatestAcqDate = 20010813
BrowseAvail = Y
LocalBrowseName = MEN-31-45_UR_2000.jpg
SiloPath = /hsm/lta3/lsat_ortho/tridecadal/etm_mosaic/31/45/N-31-45_ur_2000.tar.gz
ContrastAdjustment = EarthSat_LOCAL
```

Comment: this is where I got the file: http://glovis.usgs.gov/

Comment: Please [edit the question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/208868/edit) to update it with new information.

Comment: the bbox looks correct so reversing your lat/lon values in ArcMap should fix the issue

Comment: Are you sure you've chosen WGS 1984 UTM 31 **N** (EPSG code 32**6**31), not WGS 1984 UTM 31 **S** (EPSG code 32**7**31)?

Comment: When you drop it into ArcMap or check its extent in ArcCatalog, before you define the coordinate system (projection), what are its extent? Is it georeferenced at all? (If it isn't, it would make sense that it shows up at the equator.)

Comment: When I load the image into ArcMap it says: 'missing spatial reference'. (that's why I tried define projection). The extent is top 0.5, left -0.5, right 511.5 bottom 511.5.

Comment: I did put the N right.

Comment: I think it is maybe a missing georeference file, altough I have all the data available as metadata (extension .meta), see above.

Comment: It looks like you have a geoTIFF so the spatial reference information is hidden inside the file.  If you added the file to a new ArcGIS project with no defined data frame projection and the file appears on the equator at (0,0) and not in France then the spatial information is missing. Georeference the image.  Maybe the file is not a geoTIFF and the metadata is wrong.  Look for an associated world file (*.TWF) and place the world file in the same directory as the TIFF.

Comment: @GBG I think you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I came up with GeoTiff issue on ArcGIS/ArcMap, and figured out how to define the coordinate system for GeoTiff/Tiff using either ArcCatelog or ArcToolBox.
(a) For ArcCatelog, right click on the *.tif file and open the properties window.  Scroll down the window and find the "Spatial Reference" section, click [Edit] button to change the coordinate system to what ever you believe it is correct.  You also can find the detail description from ArcGIS Help: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/defining-or-modifying-a-raster-coordinate-system.htm

[image: Define Projection on ArcCatelog]

(b) You can also use ArcToolBox with ArcMap, using [Define Projection] to the GeoTiff/Tiff raster coordinate system.

There are couple things need to pay attention: If there is a world file (*.tfw) exist, ArcMap will read the extent information from world file and overwrite the setting on GeoTiff's infomration, however, the rest parameters such as spatial reference will follow the original GeoTiff information.

Comment: Add the image for using [Define Projection] of ArcToolBox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJIyH.png